# Inconsistency in tags for A/D and D/A conversion

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging

At the moment, we have tags [adc](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adc) and [digital-to-analog](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-to-analog). The former is more popular than the latter. Hence, I propose that:

1. [adc](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adc) be renamed [analog-to-digital](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analog-to-digital) with synonym [adc](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adc).
2. [dac](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dac) be created as a synonym for [digital-to-analog](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital-to-analog).

so that the tag names are self-descriptive and the tags themselves are easily found via the popular acronyms (used as synonyms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've made the change you suggest.

[image: Screenshot of synonyms]

---

**Older Answer Below**

I'd be tempted to go the other way:  keep <kbd>adc</kbd> and <kbd>dac</kbd> and make the longer forms synonyms. Mainly because the shorter forms include "c" (for convertor), and adding that to the longer forms would make them a little long.

Comment: I learned DSP from books written in English, so I am familiar with the acronyms. What about those who learned the material in other languages and are perhaps used to different acronyms? This is one reason to have self-descriptive tag names. The popular acronyms would still be used as synonyms, of course.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I'm OK with either! Just wanted to suggest a different take. Having the synonyms either way should work.